# How to find the values of 2 unknown variables in data set when its mean and standard deviation are known?

Tags: statistics

Suppose I have a set of values like:

2,4,5,6,8,x,y.

The mean(arithmetic mean) and standard deviation of this data set are already known. Also the mean value of x and y are also known.

How can we determine the values of x and y?

Comment: Can we find from simultaneous equations? I tried that but still could not figure them out. I am looking for a definite solution.

Answer (score 1):

We have two variables ($x,\ y$), so we need two equations. Luckily, we have two additional items of data, with which we can build our two equations:
We'll denote the mean $\mu$ and the standard deviation $\sigma$. Let's use the information regarding the mean first:
  $$ \mu = \frac{\sum z_i}{n} = \frac{25 + x +y}{7} $$
So, our first equation is:
\begin{equation}
x+y = 7\mu - 25
\end{equation}

Now let's use the information regarding the standard deviation:
$$\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum(z_i-\mu)^2}{n}$$
After some arithmetic this can be written as:
$$x^2 + 2x\mu + y^2+ 2y\mu = 7(\mu^2- \sigma^2) -50 \mu + 145$$

So now we have our two equations for two variables, and we can solve via our favorite method. If you need more help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This will result in a simple set of equations.
$$
2+4+5+6+8+x+y=7\mu
$$
with $\mu$ the mean of the set and 7 the number of datapoints in the set.

$x+y=2\mu_2$
with $\mu_2$ the mean of $x$ and $y$.
The set of this two equations should be redundant (infinite solutions) If it has no solutions, there is something wrong with the data of the question.

The last equation you need to be able to solve the problem is:
$$
(\mu-2)^2 + (\mu-4)^2 + (\mu-5)^2 +(\mu-6)^2 + (\mu-8)^2 + (\mu-x)^2 + (\mu-y)^2 = \sigma^2
$$
whereby $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the dataset.

Comment: Fine. But how are we going to find the values of x and y?

Answer (score 0):

You do not actually need to know the mean value of $x$ and $y$ in order to solve this problem. It is enough to know *either* the mean value of $x$ and $y$ *or* the mean value of all the data taken together. Just one of those mean values, plus the standard deviation, is sufficient.

---

Here's one specific way to find $x$ and $y.$

First, you have to determine which "standard deviation" is meant.
One possibility is that the given data are considered to be the entire
population whose standard deviation is measured,
that is, the "standard deviation" is
$$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac 1N \sum (x_i - \mu)^2},\tag1$$
where $N$ is the number of data values.
Another possibility is that the given data are considered to be a sample
taken from a larger population, and the "standard deviation" is defined
by the usual formula for the standard deviation of a  sample
(which is an estimate of the standard deviation of the entire population),
$$s = \sqrt{\frac 1{N-1} \sum (x_i - \mu)^2}.\tag2$$

In the following, I will suppose that the "standard deviation" was defined by
Equation $(1).$
If it actually was defined by Equation $(2),$ the following equations can be adapted to that definition by replacing $\sigma$ by 
$\left(\sqrt{\frac{N-1}{N}}\right)s$ wherever $\sigma$ appears.

In order to make this a general solution, not just applicable to the particular five given numbers in the question,
let the list of data values be
$$ x_1,\ x_2,\ x_3,\ \ldots,\ x_{N-2},\ x,\ y.$$
Then the mean of all the data is
$$ \mu = \frac1N\left(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_{N-2} + x + y\right).$$
Therefore
$$ x + y = N\mu - \sum_{i=1}^{N-2} x_i. \tag3$$
In the case where the other data and the mean of all the data are known, everything on the right-hand side of Equation $(3)$ is known,
so we can set $A = N\mu - \sum_{i=1}^{N-2} x_i$ and compute the value of $A.$
But if we know the mean of $x$ and $y$ then we can just set $A$ to twice that mean. Either way, we have
$$ x + y = A, \tag4 $$
where $A$ is a value we know how to compute. If we were given the mean of $x$ and $y$ but not $\mu,$ we can now find $\mu$ by using the equation
$$\mu = \frac1N\left(A + \sum_{i=1}^{N-2} x_i\right).$$
From now on, we suppose that $\mu$ was either given or computed by this method.

For the standard deviation, there is a well-known computational trick:
$$
 \frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \mu)^2
 = \left(\frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2\right) - \mu^2.
$$
We can therefore write
$$
\sigma^2
 = \frac 1N\left(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + \ldots
         + x_{N-2}^2 + x^2 + y^2\right) - \mu^2,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
x^2 + y^2 = N\sigma^2 - N\mu^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{N-2} x_i^2. \tag5
$$
Let $B$ be equal to the right-hand side of Equation $(5)$, which we can compute from quantities that are all known. That is, we compute the quantity $B$ and then we know that
$$ x^2 + y^2 = B. \tag6$$

Square Equation $(4)$:
$$ x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = A^2.$$
Subtract Equation $(6)$:
$$ 2xy = A^2 - B. \tag7$$
If the right-hand side of Equation $(7)$ turns out to be zero, then
one of the variables $x$ or $y$ is zero and the other is equal to $A.$
Otherwise, Equation $(7)$ implies
$$ y = \frac{A^2 - B}{2x}.$$
Plugging this back into Equation $(4)$ gives us
$$ x + \frac{A^2 - B}{2x} = A,$$
and since $x \neq 0$ this is equivalent to the quadratic equation
$$ x^2 - Ax + \frac12(A^2 - B) = 0. \tag8$$

Use the standard quadratic formula to solve for $x$ in Equation $(8).$
The two solutions are the values of $x$ and $y.$
(If there is only one solution then $x$ and $y$ are both equal to that value;
if there are no solutions then the values given in the problem statement are impossible.)